# Scoop me an icecream please

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

**Make me an icecream cone please**

We have a ton of great ice cream places here in New England.  Most of them are closed for the winter now, so...

```
   .-@@-.
  (======)
 (--------)
(==========)
(__________)
 \/\/\/\/\/
  \/\/\/\/
   \/\/\/
    \/\/
     \/
```

**GOAL**
  Output the above icecream cone exactly. (or return it from a function)

This is code golf so shortest answer wins

Comment: This seems like a strange challenge, wouldn't simply executing that as a string literal technically be a solution for some interpreted languages like JS/Python?

Comment: @JacobPersi This is a classic [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] challenge, where the aim is to compress the given string as much as possible, hardcoding is probably not too golfy

Comment: Lol - my preferred 'C' family languages again have 0 chance at this.

Comment: @dzaima yes trailing spaces and trailing new lines are fine.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan 146 bytes `f(){puts("   .-@@-.\n  (======)\n (--------)\n(==========)\n(__________)\n \\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\n  \\/\\/\\/\\/\n   \\/\\/\\/\n    \\/\\/\n     \\/");}
`

Comment: Sure - could printf() or whatever.  But, strings and C won't ever compete :)  Should have stated "chance at winning this."  My bad

Comment: @MichaelDorgan  I'm curious if there's a golfing language with an icecream-cone build-in

Comment: @cleblanc Which prints this exact text? Really, *really* unlikely.

Comment: I'd say that some of these languages feel like they were invented for code golf.  I could probably create `iCeCrEaMCoNe` that one character prints a cone and win.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan many of the languages _were_ invented for code golf, but that shouldn't discourage you from answering in production languages - here it's suggested to upvote interesting answers, and an answer in `iCeCrEaMCoNe` would not be one of those. This site even used to have a rule that you can't answer in a language( / use a feature) newer than the challenge, but that got replaced by "don't upvote trivial answers". After all, these golfing languages exist just for fun :)

Comment: Understood.  I answered one recently in Arm Assembler.  Obviously not going to win, but fun none the less :)

Comment: @dzaima I missed some memos while I was gone, apparently. That rule got replaced?  Do you have a link to the meta post?  I'd love to read through it.

Comment: @StevenH. [Here's the meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges) - it's somewhat old, but many still haven't seen it

Comment: @dzaima Isn't using a language/feature that was created specifically for the challenge still considered a standard loophole?

Comment: @KSmarts I don't think it is (or should be), it's more like an implicit loophole. I have once made (a version of) one of my answers non-competing because I felt like a thing I added (that was _mostly_ documentated) was too built-in-y for the challenge, though that built-in could very well be useful on other challenges.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
u%⅝⁾⁷‰┘Η:⅛6s⁹№K⌠RΝīL°‘§╬
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=dSUyNSV1MjE1RCV1MjA3RSV1MjA3NyV1MjAzMCV1MjUxOCV1MDM5NyUzQSV1MjE1QjZzJXUyMDc5JXUyMTE2SyV1MjMyMFIldTAzOUQldTAxMkJMJUIwJXUyMDE4JUE3JXUyNTZD)

A simple compression solution:

```
....‘    push "@-.¶===(¶----(¶=====(¶_____(¶\/\/\¶/\/\¶\/\¶/\¶\"
     §   pad with spaces and reverse horizontally
      ╬  palindromize with 0 overlap and mirroring the characters
```

[No compression version](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=QC0uJXUyMDFEJTNELSUzRF8ldTIwMUQlN0IldTAxMTMzKyolMjAlMjgrJTdEazUldTIyMkI2JXUwM0JBJXUwMUE3JTVDL20lQjElN0QlQjklQTcldTI1NkM_) - way longer as SOGLs compression works nice for this

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 95 bytes

```python
i=9;print'   .-@@-.'
while i:print['('+~i*3/4*2%22*'-=_='[i%4]+')','\/'*i][i<6].center(12);i-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PW0rqgKDOvRF1BQUFP18FBV0@dqzwjMydVIdMKLBGtrqGuXZepZaxvomWkamSkpa5rG2@rHp2pahKrra6prqMeo6@ulRkbnWljFquXnJpXklqkYWikaZ2pa2v4/z8A)

Answer (score 8):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 85 bytes

```powershell
"   .-@@-.
  (======)
 (--------)
($('='*10))
($('_'*10))"
1..5|%{" "*$_+'\/'*(6-$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lBQUFP18FBV49LQUHDFgw0uRQ0dKFAk0tDRUPdVl3L0EATwo6HsJW4DPX0TGtUq5UUlLRU4rXVY/TVtTTMdFXiNWv//wcA)

OR

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 85 bytes

```powershell
"   .-@@-.
  (======)
 (--------)"
'=','_'|%{"($($_*10))"}
1..5|%{" "*$_+'\/'*(6-$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lBQUFP18FBV49LQUHDFgw0uRQ0dKFAU4lL3VZdRz1evUa1WklDRUMlXsvQQFNTqZbLUE/PFCSooKSlEq@tHqOvrqVhpqsSr1n7/z8A)

Take your pick. In both cases, the first three lines don't have enough bytes to do any sort of compression in PowerShell.

The first case uses string multiplication to produce each of the 10-length `=` and `_` lines, while the second uses a loop and string multiplication. In either case, the last line forms the cone, looping from `1` to `5` and each iteration outputting the appropriate number of spaces followed by the appropriate number of cone pieces.

All of those strings are left on the pipeline, and the implicit `Write-Output` at program completion gives us a newline between elements for free.

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```
i\/5ñ>GÄXa/\ñS³ .-@@-.
  (¶=)
 (¸-)
(±=)
(±_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/PzNGX9r08EY798MtEYn6MYc3Bh/arKCn6@Cgq8eloKBxaJutJheQ2qGryaVxaKMtmIzX/P8fAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 695c 2f1b 35f1 3e47 c458 612f 5cf1 53b3  i\/.5.>G.Xa/\.S.
00000010: 202e 2d40 402d 2e0a 2020 28b6 3d29 0a20   .-@@-..  (.=). 
00000020: 28b8 2d29 0a28 b13d 290a 28b1 5f29       (.-).(.=).(._)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
@-.⸿Ｅ=-=⁺×ι⁺³κ)×_⁵Ｐ↙⁶)⸿‖Ｍ←¤/\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETvfkXY0wYSPYgeKgUF8WShiMeAhDTF4NqUNNXPj62BHufNG8Y8dTBeU0p1cF1EOMq1CsAPq5wr3SOUsgTBTk2Dd/e2AzrBahoH3Ar24lww4MCXRVbgMS12M61Giq7/V8XZf7urbaNg@8UHnv9utiVrYuVC8AGLWZvoxREhbJSalJSS/NAP) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
@-.⸿
```

Print the right half of the first line.

```
Ｅ=-=⁺×ι⁺³κ)
```

For each of the characters `=-=`, repeat 3 times for the first and an additional time for each subsequent character, then append a `)`, printing each result on its own line.

```
×_⁵
```

Print 5 `_`s.

```
Ｐ↙⁶
```

Print the edge of the cone.

```
)⸿
```

Print the final `)` and position the cursor inside the cone.

```
‖Ｍ←
```

Mirror the half cone.

```
¤/\
```

Fill the body of the cone.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 86 bytes

```python
n=10
while n:print['\/'*n,'('+35/n*2*'-=_='[n%4]+')','.-@@-.'][-2%n/4].center(12);n-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwFAXAfU/hRp5Gf9JE3VQC3iMNXZSAQnmKBKSnjzPHP687XSn09vm41u2XKr6Oc2MOeBso9mjQDZOhcgriPx6B9Rg7tOihZVlEIwZxNc0Y9Tcxp7Oxrp0p3pZyAw)

Working off [Lynn's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148424/20260).

Comment: `-2%n/4` is so cool :) Do you search for expressions like that manually, or do run some sort of brute force search?

Comment: @Lynn I ran a brute-forcer. I also did that for `35/n*2`, which it found as `5*7/n*2` since it doesn't know of multidigit numbers.

Comment: Ohh, that’s neat. I would love to see the source code!

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <s>115 95 94 92</s> 90 bytes

*3 bytes saved by AlexDaniel in #perl6 on irc.freenode.net*

```perl6
say "   .-@@-.
  (======)
 (--------)
({"="x 10})
({"_"x 10})";say(' 'x++$,'\/'x$--+5)xx 5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVJBSUFBQU/XwUFXj0tBQcMWDDS5FDR0oUCTS6NayVapQsHQoBbMjoeylayB2jXUFdQrtLVVdNRj9NUrVHR1tU01KyoUTP//BwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 42 bytes

```
•3[ÜAʒg‰ŽÎ<\¦•6¡εS"-.@(=_"sèJ∞}'\∞5LR×‚˜.C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcMi4@jDcxxPTUp/1LDh6N7DfTYxh5YBRc0OLTy3NVhJV89BwzZeqfjwCq9HHfNq1WOApKlP0OHpjxpmnZ6j5/z/PwA)

---

[1026344463000063444446355555](https://www.google.com/search?q=1026344463000063444446355555) is now the Icecream Number b/c nobody else has used it.

---

```
Full program: •3[ÜAʒg‰ŽÎ<\¦•6¡εS"-.@(=_"sèJ∞}'\∞5LR×‚˜.C
current >> •  ||  stack: []
current >> 6  ||  stack: [1026344463000063444446355555]
current >> ¡  ||  stack: [1026344463000063444446355555, '6']
current >> ε  ||  stack: [['102', '3444', '30000', '344444', '355555']]
For each: S"-.@(=_"sèJ∞
Full program: S"-.@(=_"sèJ∞
current >> S  ||  stack: ['102']
current >> "  ||  stack: [['1', '0', '2']]
current >> s  ||  stack: [['1', '0', '2'], '-.@(=_']
current >> è  ||  stack: ['-.@(=_', ['1', '0', '2']]
current >> J  ||  stack: [['.', '-', '@']]
current >> ∞  ||  stack: ['.-@']
stack > ['.-@@-.']
Full program: S"-.@(=_"sèJ∞
current >> S  ||  stack: ['3444']
current >> "  ||  stack: [['3', '4', '4', '4']]
current >> s  ||  stack: [['3', '4', '4', '4'], '-.@(=_']
current >> è  ||  stack: ['-.@(=_', ['3', '4', '4', '4']]
current >> J  ||  stack: [['(', '=', '=', '=']]
current >> ∞  ||  stack: ['(===']
stack > ['(======)']
Full program: S"-.@(=_"sèJ∞
current >> S  ||  stack: ['30000']
current >> "  ||  stack: [['3', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
current >> s  ||  stack: [['3', '0', '0', '0', '0'], '-.@(=_']
current >> è  ||  stack: ['-.@(=_', ['3', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
current >> J  ||  stack: [['(', '-', '-', '-', '-']]
current >> ∞  ||  stack: ['(----']
stack > ['(--------)']
Full program: S"-.@(=_"sèJ∞
current >> S  ||  stack: ['344444']
current >> "  ||  stack: [['3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4']]
current >> s  ||  stack: [['3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4'], '-.@(=_']
current >> è  ||  stack: ['-.@(=_', ['3', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4']]
current >> J  ||  stack: [['(', '=', '=', '=', '=', '=']]
current >> ∞  ||  stack: ['(=====']
stack > ['(==========)']
Full program: S"-.@(=_"sèJ∞
current >> S  ||  stack: ['355555']
current >> "  ||  stack: [['3', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5']]
current >> s  ||  stack: [['3', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5'], '-.@(=_']
current >> è  ||  stack: ['-.@(=_', ['3', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5']]
current >> J  ||  stack: [['(', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']]
current >> ∞  ||  stack: ['(_____']
stack > ['(__________)']
current >> '  ||  stack: [['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)']]
current >> ∞  ||  stack: [['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)'], '\\']
current >> 5  ||  stack: [['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)'], '\\/']
current >> L  ||  stack: [['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)'], '\\/', '5']
current >> R  ||  stack: [['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)'], '\\/', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
current >> ×  ||  stack: [['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)'], '\\/', [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
current >> ‚  ||  stack: [['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)'], ['\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/', '\\/']]
current >> ˜  ||  stack: [[['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)'], ['\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/', '\\/']]]
current >> .  ||  stack: [['.-@@-.', '(======)', '(--------)', '(==========)', '(__________)', '\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/\\/', '\\/\\/', '\\/']]
   .-@@-.
  (======)
 (--------)
(==========)
(__________)
 \/\/\/\/\/
  \/\/\/\/
   \/\/\/
    \/\/
     \/
stack > ['   .-@@-.\n  (======)\n (--------)\n(==========)\n(__________)\n \\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\n  \\/\\/\\/\\/\n   \\/\\/\\/\n    \\/\\/\n     \\/']
```

---

```
•3[ÜAʒg‰ŽÎ<\¦•               | Pushes 1026344463000063444446355555 to the stack.
-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
6¡                           | Split on 6's.
-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
  ε             }            | Loop on each piece to create the top of the icecream...
   S                         | Split into single chars.
    "-.@(=_"sè               | Substitute in the correct symbol for each number.
              J∞             | Join, then mirror.
-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
                 '\∞         | Push \/.
                    5LR      | Push [5,4,3,2,1]
                       ×     | Multiply '\/' by each 5,4,3,2 and 1.
                        ‚˜   | Join top to bottom.
                          .C | Center w/ newlines.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 50 bytes

```
00000000: 5350 50d0 d375 70d0 d5e3 5250 d0b0 0503  SPP..up...RP....
00000010: 4d2e 050d 5d28 d0e4 020b c224 34e2 e100  M...](.....$4...
00000020: a82a 461f 0681 9a91 980a 0896 0284 0161  .*F............a
00000030: 0100                                     ..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc0xDsIwDAXQnVP8gQExWI4Tl5QDsCFVMDMkJLCAxNLzB7dUgpE/WJaS/5zHnB/1Pj5b4yV7qFeGcmEUv1Ps5k2rh4o9FM4MVvbAeRiIxhcRnWwhWn0EZ0YoUqdfBVokWqkGsHDGVSTAhyqojhk4Wu@ymdq0Dl9DzEhREkLnbuAuOvSptxE5gWPfmRaNdJ0DaHugn6TF8GbwfOSPELX2Bg)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 171 bytes

```
i;p(c,n,o){for(printf("%*c",o,i?32:40);n--;)printf(c);puts(i?"":")");}f(){p(".-@@-.",i=1,3);--i;p("=",6,3);p("-",8,2);p("=",10,1);p("_",10,1);for(i=6;--i;)p("\\/",i,6-i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BCoNADETvfoUECpuSWLVFiovohwilLFhy6LpYexK/fRvF5jTJkHnj@OVcjGKDceRpxGUYJxMm8fNg4HR2QCNJey3rW47WM1s8TIc2fOePkRagBgS062BwCQYy7jrOgKQp6IqWeUuHBqjaVpUMdKcSj2uRU7Hrx19vFaSp9k9Uo@8vmkYVi0Ki0tP3U7zBZElSHcXaZI0/)

## C, 146 bytes

```
f(){puts("   .-@@-.\n  (======)\n (--------)\n(==========)\n(__________)\n \\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\n  \\/\\/\\/\\/\n   \\/\\/\\/\n    \\/\\/\n     \\/");}
```

Just prints the hardcoded string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oLSkWENJQUFBT9fBQVcvJk9BQcMWDDSBbA1dKAByoMJQKY14OAApjInRR0FAY9D5Cqg8BWQ2iKOkaV37PzOvRCE3MTNPQ5OrmgskAXSjNVftfwA)

Comment: You can do better than this I thinks...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>125</s> <s>120</s> <s>119</s> <s>116</s> 106 bytes

- Saved three bytes thanks to [AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42963/admborkbork); golfed `in range(5,0,~0)` to `in[5,4,3,2,1]`.

```python
print"   .-@@-.\n  (======)\n "+"(%s)\n"*3%("-"*8,"="*10,"_"*10),
for _ in 5,4,3,2,1:print" "*(6-_)+_*"\/"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw7CoAwEAV7T7E8EJJ14y8qIggeREgn2kRRG08fPzjNTDXbdc6rL0PY9sWfIKLUDINJR0@k@g/9NBKo@HgKbGMFA24FPbjIBe6Vlmhad3K0eKqlEiulFN0/BavGOJ04xpghhBs)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 104 bytes

Borrowed a trick from [Jonathan Frech's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148416/59487), and thanks to him for saving me some bytes too.

```python
print"   .-@@-.\n  (======)\n "+"(%s)\n"*3%("-"*8,"="*10,"_"*10),
i=5
while i:print(6-i)*" "+"\/"*i;i-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69ESUFBQU/XwUFXLyZPQUHDFgw0gWwlbSUN1WIgS0nLWFVDSVdJy0JHyVZJy9BARykeRGnqcGXamnKVZ2TmpCpkWoFN0zDTzdTUUgJpjtFX0sq0ztS1Nfz/HwA)

---

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 108 bytes

```python
print"""   .-@@-.
  (======)
 (--------)
(==========)
(__________)"""
i=5
while i:print(6-i)*" "+"\/"*i;i-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69ESUlJQUFBT9fBQVePS0FBwxYMNLkUNHShQJMLKgiR0IiHA02gZq5MW1Ou8ozMnFSFTCuwiRpmupmaWkoKStpKMfpKWpnWmbq2hv//AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 50 bytes

```
5õ_ç"\\/"
c[AA8,6]£"({Xç"_=-="gY})"Ãp".-@"ê1¹w û ·
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NfVf5yJcXC8iCmNbQUE4LDZdoyIoe1jnIl89LT0iZ1l9KSLDcCIuLUAi6jG5dyD7ILc=&input=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 92 bytes

```perl
say'   .-@@-.
  (======)
 (--------)
(==========)
(__________)';$_='\/'x6;say while s%\\/% %
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJdQUFBT9fBQVePS0FBwxYMNLkUNHShQJMLKgiR0IiHA011a5V4W/UYffUKM2ugSQrlGZk5qQrFqjEx@qoKqv///8svKMnMzyv@r@trqmdgaAAA)

Comment: Don't you need to count the input towards the byte count?  Otherwise just input the entire string...

Comment: There is no input.  That was just a TIO leftover from something else I was doing.

Comment: cool, got it thanks.

Comment: +1. You can save a couple using RLE decoding, but I couldn't get using `;` as a delimiter for `s///` working for some reason. On mobile so can't do anything too much! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJdQUFBT9fBQVePS0FBw8xWk0tBw0JXk0vD1hLI1oi3jNdUt60r1o9J0dDT1FcxrFBR009PLbJWibdVj9FXrzCzBhqiUJ6RmZOqUGwdE6NvrWD9//@//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 97 bytes

```ruby
i=-1
puts ['   .-@@-.']+123455543.digits.map{|n|(i+=1;i<4?"(#{'=-=_'[i]*n*2})":'\/'*n).center 12}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P9NW15CroLSkWCFaXUFBQU/XwUFXTz1W29DI2MTU1NTEWC8lMz2zpFgvN7GguiavRiNT29bQOtPGxF5JQ7la3VbXNl49OjNWK0/LqFZTyUo9Rl9dK09TLzk1ryS1SMHQqPb/fwA)

First time ever using Ruby, so tips are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 202 bytes

This is pretty terrible, its more bytes than just defining the string and printing that even.

```
print("   .-@@-.")
print("  ("+"="*6+")")
print(" ("+"-"*8+")")
print("("+"="*10+")")
print("("+"_"*10+")")
print(" "+"\/"*5)
print("  "+"\/"*4)
print("   "+"\/"*3)
print("    "+"\/"*2)
print("     \/")
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0lBQUFP18FBV09JkwsupKGkrWSrpGWmraSJJAwS1VXSskARhSo1NMAQjccQVQCKxugraZkiWQUVMkESgokZI4vBBI1QBBWAQpr//wMA)

Comment: You can use `\n` instead of separate `print` statements

Comment: [148 bytes](https://tio.run/##RczLCoAgFIThVznMKk27WdFG8EGEVkFtTKpNT2/ahXb/x8D485hXp0Lw2@KODERUSGNkARE7Qw4N3udgyYkSfHj4jnX1c/xJkbYE79LP223qD@rGp@YRxRb75DWsAwvhAg) using this approach

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```
5RU⁾\/ẋ
5R×⁶ż¢Y
3,6,8,10,10j1ż“ “.-@@-.¶  (“=“)¶ (“-“)¶(“=“)¶(“_“)¶”P€;¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9806PD0R43bju4xDQp91LgvRv/hrm6VQ0siuYx1zHQsdAwNgCjL8OieRw1zFIBYT9fBQVfv0DYFBQ0gzxaINYEcEFsXwkYSBjHjIcxHDXMDHjWtsT606P9/AA)

**Explanation:**

```
5RU⁾\/ẋ    Link 1. Generate list of "\/"s for cone.
5RU        Range 5, reverse. Gets [5,4,3,2,1].
   ⁾\/     Literal string "\/".
      ẋ    Repeat. Gets ["\/\/\/\/\/","\/\/\/\/","\/\/\/","\/\/","\/"].

5R×⁶ż¢Y    Link 2. Generate rest of cone.
5R         Range 5. Gets [1,2,3,4,5].
  ×⁶       Repeat " " that many times. Gets [" ","  ","   ","    ","     "]
    ż¢     Zip that with the ¢ones. Gets a list of alternating space and cones.
      Y    Join with newlines. This puts it all together for the big cone.

3,6,8,10,10j1ż“ “.-@@-.¶  (“=“)¶ (“-“)¶(“=“)¶(“_“)¶”P€;¢    Link 3. Generate the top and put it on the cone.
10,10,8,6j1;1U                                                Generate list 3,1,6,1,8,1,10,1,10. Does this by joining [10,10,8,6] with ones, appending a one, and reversing.
               “   .-@@-.¶  (“=“)¶ (“-“)¶(“=“)¶(“_“)¶”        List of strings. This separates the completed parts from the non completed parts.
              ż                                               Zip 'em together. Gets [number, string, number, string, ...]
                                                      P€      Get the product of €ach. This completes the non completed strings by repeating them.
                                                        ;¢    Attach the ¢one to the end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 117 bytes

```
Column[Join[{".-@@-."},"("<>#<>")"&/@{"="~(T=Table)~6,"-"~T~8,"="~T~10,"_"~T~10},T[""<>T["\/",i],{i,5,1,-1}]],Center]
```

Outputs
[image]

you can test it on [wolfram sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) (although the fonts they use may destort the result a little)

Comment: Interestingly `\/` is a special character. I couldn't find what it's used for so I asked on Mma.SE: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200673/61597

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 58 bytes

```
jm.[12@,*d"\/"@,".-@@-."j@*Vj11494 11"-=_="d"()"ndTgd6;_ST
```

[Watch it in action](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm.%5B12%40%2C%2ad%22%5C%2F%22%40%2C%22.-%40%40-.%22j%40%2aVj11494+11%22-%3D_%3D%22d%22%28%29%22ndTgd6%3B_ST&debug=0)!

Answer (score 1):

## C, 138 bytes

```c
f(i,j){puts("   .-@@-.\n  (======)\n (--------)\n(==========)\n(__________)");for(j=1;++j<7;i=puts(""))for(;i<7;)printf(i++<j?" ":"\\/");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEER/ZdnTLjEtngTTYD8kUCQQ2YCx1HoqfnvcavCddmaY2WhvMdaaSA6Zt/m1PgkBoLPjaLtQAMh/Yb3JNlQ0u0U0/WFklx4LZX90xuTh5MT/ZpF5D5yox/MiZdWvxgz5goBnDKHX6rver1KIt0S7@AA)

Comment: Suggest `j=6;--j;puts(""))for(i=7;--i;)printf(&L"⽜ "[i>j]` instead of `j=1;++j<7;i=puts(""))for(;i<7;)printf(i++<j?" ":"\\/"`

Answer (score 1):

## C 165 bytes

```
y,x,z;f(){for(puts("   .-@@-.");y++<9;)for(;x=++x%14;)z=y+3-y/4,putchar(x<13?y<5?x-7^z-1?7-x^z?abs(x-7)<z?y<4?y&1?61:45:95:32:40:41:x+y>16|y-x>3?32:x+y&1?92:47:10);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### VimL, 76 bytes

```
a   .-@@-.␤  ␤ ␛k6A=␛j8A-␛o␛10A=␛o␛10A_␛qaI(␛A)␛kq3@aGo ␛5A\/␛qayypxxI ␛q3@a
```

[Animated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDZ3l.gif) with [vimanim.py](https://gist.github.com/lynn/5f4f532ae1b87068049a23f7d88581c5).

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>137</s> 136 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```c
main(i){for(puts("   .-@@-.\n  (======)\n (--------)\n(==========)\n(__________)");8<printf("%*c%s\n",++i,92,"/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/"+i*2););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOi2/SKOgtKRYQ0lBQUFP18FBVy8mT0FBwxYMNIFsDV0oAHKgwlApjXg40FTStLawKSjKzCtJ01BS1UpWLY7JU9LR1s7UsTTSUdKPiUFBStqZWkaa1prWtf//AwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](//git.io/Cubically), <s>345</s> 336 bytes

```
⇒@@@
RU+30f1+3-00@-2+3@+4@@-4@+2-3@-110@+31-4@@+2-4@+10f1f1-3+0@-400@+31-4@+2-4@+3-10f1f1@@-4+1@-400@+11@+10f1f1f1@-3+0@-400@+11@+4110@f1f1f1-22@-400@+31-4@+220@-43@+43@-43@+43@-43@+43@-43@+43@-43@-4000@+31-4@@+220@-43@+43@-43@+43@-43@+43@-43@-4000@+31-4f1+220@-43@+43@-43@+43@-43@-4000@+31-4f1@+220@-43@+43@-43@-4000@+31-4f1@@+220@-43@
```

Found via [this tool](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141839/61563) and golfed via search-and-replace, with a couple custom optimizations.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/NCQJBDIXvthIC@ZkCXg2CBejCgrDXPWwF3i3RRsaEcXEGUU/DvO97IZnWy3U6L8tW6@N2B3A4nshlVnIWARs5qABcQMYOVhWQa/wziFRDnpWdwi6yw8acG80@6Yur7qUAXS/zkuMbYrNxoKWY2/jPNzvdin9anR03f7MH63PoiN@81ic)

---

Alternate method:

## 391 bytes (doesn't modify cube)

```
+5/1+3@@@:1/1+5@5.0+2@@5.0-2@-4@:5/1+3@@:4/1+4@:5+2/1+51@@@@@@:5/1+4@:1/1+1@:5/1+3@:4/1+4@5.05.05.05.05.05.05.05.0:5/1+4@:1/1+1@:4/1+4@:5+2/1+51@@@@@@@@@@:5/1+4@:1/1+1@:4/1+4@:5/1+55@@@@@@@@@@-51@:1/1+1@:5/1+3@:2/1+55@-5@+5@-5@+5@-5@+5@-5@+5@-5@:1/1+1@:5/1+3@@:2/1+55@-5@+5@-5@+5@-5@+5@-5@:1/1+1@:5/1+3@@@:2/1+55@-5@+5@-5@+5@-5@:1/1+1@:5/1+3@@@@:2/1+55@-5@+5@-5@:1/1+1@:5/1+3@@@@@:2/1+55@-5@
```